# Prevent a thread from being unscheduled

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I try to implement something that prevent a thread from being interrupted by other running threads (inside of a single process), using the winapi.

My first ID was to put this thread to a higher priority, regarding documentation (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it should prevents other from being executed (of course if my thread does not fall to any WAIT state).

But, and I can't really get why, other thread are still being scheduled after this "trick".

I can't get any other idea than using `SuspendThread()` on all other threads...

Is there some cleaner way to do so? Or have you got any advice regarding my issue?

Comment: "interrupted by other threads" which other threads?  In your own program or in the entire system? Because the latter is going to REALLY HARD, if not impossible.

Comment: Maybe you should look into using a lock/mutex/critical section instead.

Comment: A thread can enter a wait state for reasons you don't expect, in basically any system function you call. And if you're worried about data races or similar, then use proper locking mechanisms like mutexes or semaphores.

Comment: It's impossible to have an uninterruptible thread. If you could do that, and your program ran on a single core processor, the computer would freeze, unable to react to hardware input. Even in old Windows 3.1 (a non-preentive cooperative system with only one 'system-wide thread'), your code would be interrupted by hardware events. If you give a bit of more information about what problem you are trying to solve, maybe someone can suggest a proper solution for yo.

Comment: XY-Problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to prevent this particular thread to be interrupted by other thread (of the same process).

Comment: You already said that. Why do you need this?

Comment: The thing is, I'm currently working on a API on top of windows. And I have to provide such a functionality. Don't really know up to which goal for now.

Comment: Use Fibers, then you have control over scheduling...

Comment: Aside from setting the priority, set the processor affinity so that no other threads are running on the same core.

Comment: @joshpoley: How should this be done? You cannot change the affinity of some system processes...

Comment: @JochenKalmbach, The question stated that you only cared about the threads inside of a single process. But if you do want to rude, you can run as SYSTEM and then you can move all other processes' threads to another core (we've done this for performance benchmarks).

Comment: @joshpoley This was exactly my problem! I didn't think about multicore at all... Thank you because that explained a lot behavior on my side :) If you put your solution as an answer I will check it as accepted answer.

Comment: @JochenKalmbach can just add that (use `SetProcessAffinityMask` or `SetThreadAffinityMask`) to his answer.

Comment: @joshpoley: Done... hope it is correctly... also added comment about SuspendThread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are scheduled OS wide and not only for *one* process. You can change the prio to 31. This will be the highest possible... but if other threads also runs with prio 31, your thread will also interrupted... Also all hardware-events (IRQs) will have higher prio than 31...

If you just want to have an "Process-wide" solution, I suggest to use [Fibers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). With fibers, you can do your own scheduling and also "prevent" other "Fibers" to "interrupt" your task. Of course, it might still be "interrupted" by an other thread. But if you run your thread with prio 31, this should be no big problem....

With this scenario, we run very high responsive (almost) realtime systems with Profibus connections... Also SQL server is using the fiber mode for optimized and very high performance mode.

Alternatively you can modify (restrict) the process affinity mask for all other processes ([SetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))! To modify *all* processes you need to start your process as SYSTEM (for example via a service).

If you just care about your own process you can modify (restrict) the thread affinity of all other threads ([SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) in your own process!

Be aware, that it makes no sense to restrict your "important" thread to a specific CPU! This will only restrict your thread. But you must restrict all other threads/processes in order to get your "important" thread the best performance!

Also be aware that you never should consider using [`SuspendThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)! This might lead to dead-locks... see also: http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=6 / http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=16